# Use separate aws-cli credentials & config in a virtualenv

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualenv

From a virtualenv, is it possible to set the aws-cli to default to `~/venv/.aws/credentials` instead of to `~/.aws/credentials`.

I realize I can just use `--profile` on each aws command, but it seems beneficial to default a specific "test/project environment" to point to specific credentials.

I've searched ways to do this, but not much luck since everything seems to point to posts on boto.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have separate AWS credential files per virtual environment. What you can do is, you can set the AWS profile as an environment variable.

```
export AWS_PROFILE=staging
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, "it is not possible" is the perfect answer so I know! That's a good idea with the `export` I will do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this fits the requirements 100%, but awscli can [retrieve credentials from an external process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sourcing-external.html). You could, for example, set your default AWS credentals config to execute a script like this:

```
[default]
cat ~/venv/.aws/credentials
```

And then make sure that `~/venv/.aws/credentials` are in the correct format, for example:

```
{
  "Version": 1,
  "AccessKeyId": "an AWS access key",
  "SecretAccessKey": "your AWS secret access key",
  "SessionToken": "the AWS session token for temporary credentials", 
  "Expiration": "ISO8601 timestamp when the credentials expire"
}
```

Obviously you could make the script do something more sophisticated than `cat`, perhaps searching a hierarchy of folders.

The `AWS_PROFILE=xyz` option is likely simpler, of course.